# ¿Cómo y con qué ha sido realizada esta página web?css

Tags: javascript, html, css

me ha llamado bastante la atención esta página web y me gustaría saber como ha sido realizada. Me refiero si ha sido exclusivamente con HTML, CSS y animaciones con JavaScript o se ha utilizado algún framerwork como Bootstrap.

Muchas gracias.
https://eclipse-rp.net/

Comment: En el navegador --> `Herramientas de desarrollador (F12 en Firefox > Pestaña Red` > Mira los recursos que carga (Eso es con lo que está hecho).

Comment: Definitivamente bootstrap.

Comment: por lo que veo fue hecha con Bootstrap 4, OWL Carousel, JQuery, y FontAwesome.

Comment: Bootstrap, fijate en los archivos css con el inspector (F12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En chrome tienes un plugin que te da toda esa información: [wappalyzer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/wappalyzer?hl=es)

> It detects content management systems, web shops, web servers, JavaScript frameworks, analytics tools and many more

saludos